# Combine / merge two multiline outputs into one "lineFromA : lineFromB"

Tags: bash

**Input 1 of 2:**

```
$ xinput list --id-only
2
4
12
3
```

**Input 2 of 2:**

```
$ xinput list --name-only
Virtual core pointer
Virtual core XTEST pointer
SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad
Virtual core keyboard
```

**Expected output:**

```
2 : Virtual core pointer
4 : Virtual core XTEST pointer
12 : SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad
3 : Virtual core keyboard
```

I can't get this to work. No matter what always an issue with spaces in names.

**This is as close as I got:**

```
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
ids=($(xinput list --id-only))
names=($(xinput list --name-only))
combined=
for (( i=0; i<${#ids[@]}; i++ )); do
    temp=$(printf "%s %s $s\n" "${ids[i]}" $(echo "${names[i]}" | tr -d "\n" ) "${ids[i]}")
    combined="${combined} ${temp}"
done

echo "${combined}"
IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

**output:**

```
$ ./touchpad 
 2 Virtual core pointer 
2   4 Virtual core XTEST pointer 
4   12 SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad 
12   3 Virtual core keyboard 
3   5 Virtual core XTEST keyboard 
5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use arrays to hold the values.

```
#!/bin/bash
ids=()
names=()

while read id ; do
    ids+=("$id")
done < <(xinput list --id-only)

while read name ; do
    names+=("$name")
done < <(xinput list --name-only)

for ((i=0; i<${#ids[@]}; ++i)) ; do
    printf '%s: %s\n' "${ids[i]}" "${names[i]}"
done
```

You can even use `paste` to combine the outputs directly:

```
paste <(xinput list --id-only) <(xinput list --name-only)
```

or use this to populate an associative array:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A device

while read id name; do
    device[$id]=$name
done < <(paste <(xinput list --id-only) \
       <(xinput list --name-only))

for id in "${!device[@]}" ; do
    printf '%s: %s\n' "$id" "${device[$id]}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also utilize `paste` like this:

```
paste -d' : ' <(xinput list --id-only) /dev/null{,} <(xinput list --name-only)
```